# Navigation bar bugs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a website and I was planning on having the website containing only one page with multiple sections through out the page, with a navigation bar at the top of the screen to make it to where you can click on the section on the navigation bar at will scroll you to the section. When you click on the section it will also highlight the section you are currently on.

The problem I am having is when I click on the section it will not highlight/select the section.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet"  href="index.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="nav-bar">
            <ul>
                <li class="logo">BOS</li>
                 <div> <li id="btn">Contact</li> </div>
                 <div> <li id="btn">Services</li> </div>
                 <div> <li id="btn">About</li> </div>
                 <div> <li class="selected" id="btn">Home</li> </div>
            </ul>           
        </div>

         <div class="slide-out">        
         </div>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

This is the JavaScript i was using to select the section:

```
var main = function () {
$('.nav-bar #btn').click(function() {
    $(".nav-bar #btn").removeClass("selected");

    $(this).addClass("selected");
}); 
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

Also, I am using Brackets (brackets.io), and it will work correctly when using the "live preview" within Brackets but won't work on any browser I test it on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Ids should be always unique. Use class instead of Id.

```
<ul>
                <li class="logo">BOS</li>
                 <div> <li class="btn">Contact</li> </div>
                 <div> <li class="btn">Services</li> </div>
                 <div> <li class="btn">About</li> </div>
                 <div> <li class="btn selected">Home</li> </div>
            </ul>
```

And then try :

```
var main = function () {
$('.nav-bar .btn').click(function() {
    $(".nav-bar .btn").removeClass("selected");

    $(this).addClass("selected");
}); 
};

$(document).ready(main);
```